# Problem with setting up datetimepicker in Django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

Im currently using Tempus Dominus for my datetime picker in django. In my models.py I have

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(
    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
        'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'
    })
)
```

and in my template I have

```
     <h5>When would you like to pickup? *</h5>
          <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
            <input type="text">
            {{ form.date }}
            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <script>
            $(function () {
              $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
              });
            });
          </script>
        </div>
```

I want my end result to look like this

[image]

However, when I try to add in `{{ form.date }}` instead of a input field, it would only show the calendar icon with no input field.

I of course want the datetime info in the database but I've been scratching my head for the past couple hours trying to link them up, Im sure im missing something stupid. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally forget to pass form to context in the `views.py`? I followed all the things you wrote and I have the final result. I take sample html content from the [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html#direct-usage). Only thing I've added is passing form to template from `views.py`. This is my `views.py` file.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import DateForm


def home(request):
    context = {"form": DateForm()}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```